# How to convert absolute paths to relative paths in .ini file?

Tags: path

```
              Adviant
                 |

               Deluxe
                 |
32bit ----------------------- Forms
```

How to set up the relative path for Deluxe and Forms? Below is the .ini file. Adviant, Deluxe, 32bit and Forms represent folders in the illustration above

---

```
[Preferences]
ConnectionPref=0
PartnerOffers=1

[UninstallInfo]
ProgramFolder=Adviant Deluxe
RegFolder=Adviant Deluxe
InstDir=C:\Program Files\Adviant\Deluxe

[EngineOptions]
FormPath1=C:\Program Files\Adviant\Deluxe\Forms

[Cache]
Build=Yes
```

---

The .ini file itself is inside 32bit folder

I tried the following and it did not work

```
InstDir=..\..\..\Deluxe
FormPath1=..\..\Forms
```

---

Very simple! The program worked with absolute path in the .ini file above. When I tried to convert absolute path to relative path, it said "Forms are missing, program cannot start".

I want to know how to convert the absolute paths to relative paths for portability.

The tricky part for me is that, the .ini file is in the 32bit folder and not in the main program folder which is Deluxe folder.

I hope this explanation clarifies thing a bit.

Comment: Anybody else has any suggestions? I've tried with both forward or backward slashes and different combinations of dots and it's not working. @ Tech1337, do you have any additional suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
InstDir=../
FormPath1=../Forms/
```

That should fix it. Try it and let me know.

Comment: I've tried it and it still said: Forms are missing. Application cannot start...  Thanks for the effort though, I appreciate it.

Comment: Actually try
InstDir=../
 FormPath1=../Forms/

Comment: No, it did not work. Same error: Forms are missing. Application cannot start. I also think any combination should be with a backward slash since it's a windows application.